# Calculation of $DF$ of $F(x,y,z)=(x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2,xyz)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Calculate the differential, the Jacobian matrix $JF(1,0,2)$ and $[DF(1,0,2)](2,3,0)$ of 
>   $$F(x,y,z)=(x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2,xyz)$$

My thoughts so far:

the differential is the linear mapping $dF:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ $$dF=(x+y+z,2x^2+2y^2+2z^2,3xyz)$$
the Jacobian matrix is $$JF(1,0,2)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$
and I'm confused about $[DF(1,0,2)](2,3,0)$

If we were in fewer dimensions, $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then we would think of it as the directional derivative, so $$[Df(1,0,2)](2,3,0)=D_{(2,3,0)}f(1,0,2)=\nabla   f(1,0,2)\cdot (2,3,0)=(\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(1,0,2),\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(1,0,2))\cdot (2,3,0)$$

But in this exercise, $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$.

The Jacobi matrix generalizes the gradient, so $[DF(1,0,2)](2,3,0)$ is the directional derivative (?) and 
$$[DF(1,0,2)](2,3,0)=D_{(2,3,0)}F(1,0,2)=JF(1,0,2)\cdot (2,3,0)$$ is this the correct way to calculate it ?

I am confused because I don't understand whether $[DF(1,0,2)](2,3,0)$ is the

- derivative of F, or
- directional derivative of F, or
- Fréchet derivative of F  ?

Moreover, I don't understand what is the difference between Fréchet and directional derivative? By looking at their definition they look the same.

Answer (score 2):

The differential of a function at a point is a linear map that approximates the change in the function near that point. If you have $F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$, then $dF:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$, as you’ve stated. Think of it a a rule that assigns a linear transformation to each point in the domain of $F$. Its matrix representation *is* the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives.  Your Jacobian at $(1,0,2)$ looks right, but it doesn’t match what you’ve written down for $dF$.

Finally, I suspect that what is meant by the expression $[DF(1,0,2)](2,3,0)$ is “take the linear transformation assigned to $(1,0,2)$ by the differential and apply it to the displacement vector $(2,3,0)$,” i.e., apply the Jacobian that you’ve already computed to the vector $(2,3,0)$.

Comment: you mean that it should be $dF=(x+y+z,2x^2+2y^2+2z^2,3xyz)$?

Comment: @maria886 No. $dF_{\mathbf x}$ is a linear transformation such that $f(\mathbf x+\mathbf h)=f(\mathbf x)+df_{\mathbf x}[\mathbf h] + o(\mathbf h)$. Each component of $df[\mathbf h]$ is going to be a linear function of $(dx, dy, dz)^T$ that depends on the point $\mathbf x$. You had to have calculated it already in order to compute the Jacobian at $(1,0,2)$.